# Typecasting with a class that is protected

Tags: java, reflection, vert.x

I am trying to override some class of vertx web project, since I have to change some of the features. So the tricky part comes here.

```
  @Override
  public void reroute(HttpMethod method, String path) {
    int split = path.indexOf('?');

    if (split == -1) {
      split = path.indexOf('#');
    }

    if (split != -1) {
      log.warn("Non path segment is not considered: " + path.substring(split));
      // reroute is path based so we trim out the non url path parts
      path = path.substring(0, split);
    }

    /*((HttpServerRequestWrapper) request).setMethod(method);
    ((HttpServerRequestWrapper) request).setPath(path);*/
    ((HttpServerRequestWrapper) request).setMethod(method);
    ((HttpServerRequestWrapper) request).setPath(path);
    request.params().clear();
    // we need to reset the normalized path
    normalisedPath = null;
    // we also need to reset any previous status
    statusCode = -1;
    // we need to reset any response headers
    response().headers().clear();
    // special header case cookies are parsed and cached
    if (cookies != null) {
      cookies.clear();
    }
    // reset the end handlers
    if (headersEndHandlers != null) {
      headersEndHandlers.clear();
    }
    if (bodyEndHandlers != null) {
      bodyEndHandlers.clear();
    }

    failure = null;
    restart();
  }
```

This code throws me a compilation error saying:

```
'HttpServerRequestWrapper cannot be accessed from outside package'
```

I know for a fact that we can use reflection to create objects of a class that cannot be accessed. Can reflection be used in this case? How can I fix such an issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What about getting the `Class` object and then calling the methods on your specific (uncasted) object?

I assume `request` is a class attribute of type `HttpServerRequestWrapper`. Then, this is what I suggest:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

...

private final Method setMethod;
private final Method setPath;

public MyConstructor() {
    Method tmp1 = null, tmp2 = null;
    try {
        final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper");
        tmp1 = clazz.getMethod("setMethod", HttpMethod.class);
        tmp1.setAccessible(true);
        tmp2 = clazz.getMethod("setPath", String.class);
        tmp2.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // do something
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // do something
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // do something
    }
    this.setMethod = tmp1;
    this.setPath = tmp2;
}
...

@Override
public void reroute(HttpMethod method, String path) {
    ...
    try {
        this.setMethod.invoke(request, method);
        this.setPath.invoke(request, path);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // do something
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // do something
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**: I updated this answer based on @GotoFinal's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In java 8 and/or without modules it is possible to just place class like that in same package as original one to get access to all package-default classes.

Otherwise you need to use reflections like in other response, but I would add that it is good idea to cache that `Class` and `Method` instance, as using `Class.forName` and `clazz.getDeclaredMethod` each time will slowdown code.

Comment: Good call. I updated the answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HttpServerRequestWrapper implements HttpServerRequest. So, you can change "HttpServerRequestWrapper" to "HttpServerRequest" in your code. But remember that by doing so, you'll only be able to call methods specified in the interface.

You can see those methods in https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/rxjava/core/http/HttpServerRequest.html.

Comment: Cannot do that as the method 'setMethod' belongs only to HttpServerRequestWrapper.